# Get Current User using SPUtility

Tags: javascript, sputility

I want to check if current user = "xxx" and make the field "yyy" as Read Only.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();

    if(userName == "xxx") {
        SPUtility.GetSPField('yyy').MakeReadOnly();

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName or _spPageContextInfo.userEmail or other info from _sppagecontextinfo.

Comment: can you give me an exemple please?

Comment: var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(); instead of this you can simply use var userName = _spPageContextInfo.userEmail; if your username field expects email address.

Comment: Thnx Bhaskar It work :) can you make your comment as answer?

Comment: Great !! Sure I will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bhaskar : For this Solution we can use only UserId and it work well :)

But if we have to use a `loginName` we can do This :

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/sputility.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/getuserbyid("+ userid + ")";
        var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
        $.ajax({
            url : requestUri,
            contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers : requestHeaders,
            success : onSuccess,
            error : onError
        });

        function onSuccess(data, request){
            var loginName = data.d.Title;
            if(loginName == "xxx") {
                SPUtility.GetSPField('yyy').MakeReadOnly();
            }
        }

        function onError(error) {
            alert("error");
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName - will this not give you similar result ?

Comment: there are no userDisplayName. Only userId. If I have the IDs of the other users it will be perfect and short.       http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can get user information from `_spPageContextInfo` to validate eg.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userName = _spPageContextInfo.userEmail;

    if(userName == "xxx") {
        SPUtility.GetSPField('yyy').MakeReadOnly();

    }
}
```

like email you can also get `userDisplayName` , `userLoginId`, `userId` etc.